# Some keyboard shortcuts do not work win 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, shortcuts

Some keyboard shortcuts are not working on my Win 10 Pro machine. Specifically, ALT+F12. Alt and F12 work separately. Also, ALt + F4 works, and Ctrl + F12 works, so I know this isn't an n-key rollover type issue.

I tried with a second keyboard, in a completely different USB port (which is also on a different USB controller), to the same affect.

Is something capturing the press and not passing it on? Can anyone help me find the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a Fn - FnLk toggle on your keyboard that is affecting the keys you see?  I have that on my machine which is why I ask.

Comment: Thanks for responding, John. I don't have an FnLk on either of the keyboards I tried with.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Try the initial a Windows 10 repair steps. From an admin command prompt, run DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  . Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW  . Restart when done and test

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, John. I ended up using MS Spy++ (part of the C++ workload install in VS) to find which process was capturing my hotkeys. I then discovered it is Nvidia GeForce Experience. I've removed all hotkey combos from that and everything is now very happy. Thanks for taking the time ti offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MS Spy++ (part of the C++ workload install in VS) to find which process was capturing my hotkeys. See this thread here:[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/43645062#43645062).

I then discovered it is Nvidia GeForce Experience. I've removed all hotkey combos from that and everything is now happy.